# Why does the drop shadow at the bottom of Bootstrap navbar cut off at beginning and end

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The box shadow I have applied at the bottom of the navbar cut's off short at the beginning and end.

CSS

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -8px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -8px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
```

[image: Navbar]

Updated with Bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/WgAVhmb8ql

Comment: Reproduce the issue on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/).

Comment: Is the navbar inside a container? Is it fixed to the top of the page or inline?

Comment: Navbar is not within any container and is not fixed to the top of the page.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py http://www.bootply.com/WgAVhmb8ql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by the `-8px` which is the value for the "spread" - you're telling the shadow to spread by a negative amount, so it basically retracts from the edges.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow

> Specifies the ***spread distance***. Positive values cause the shadow to
>   expand in all directions by the specified radius. Negative values
>   cause the shadow to contract.

Try removing the negative spread and playing about with the other values in the shadow, e.g.

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
```

http://www.bootply.com/t7qfN7Wk3w

Comment: When playing about I had a feeling this was the cause but wasn't too sure, thank you very much for your help.